# Why do these two methods give different performances when using multi-s3?

Tags: node.js, multer-s3

I think they're both the same binary buffers, but I want to know if they're doing a different performance.

```
let paramS3 = {
  Bucket: "sopt24",
  Key:  dateString+req.file.originalname,
  Body: new Buffer(req.file.buffer, "binary")
  // or
  // Body: req.file.buffer
};
```

Those...

```
console.log( req.file.buffer )
console.log( new Buffer(req.file.buffer, "binary") )
```

... seem to give exactly the same result.

Comment: Don't really get why one needs to copy a buffer here (especially using deprecated `new Buffer(buffer)` syntax, and not `Buffer.from(...)`)

Comment: @raina77ow Thank you for your Answer, I wonder why a corrupted file is stored in S3 when 'req.file.buffer' is inserted into the body.